# Json.net does not invoke custom ContractResolver for a custom Excetion

Tags: json.net

I need to pass an information about custom exception types from WebApi web service to the client. For that I'm trying to use Json.Net serializer + CustomContractResolver to have a control over what is being sent to the client.

```
public class Data //: Exception
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public Data()
    {
        Prop1 = "Hi";
        Prop2 = "Bye";
    }
}

public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    // !!! Method is not being invoked if Data is inherited from Exception
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        property.ShouldSerialize = instance => property.PropertyName == "Prop1";
        return property;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
                           {
                               ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver() 
                           };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Data(), settings);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I've tried to run this code with Json.Net 6.0.4 and 6.0.6. Were using .Net Framework 4.5.0 and 4.5.2. But the issue is the same - when data is inherited from Exception CustomContractResolver is not working (nuget config line: package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.6" targetFramework="net45" or package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.6" targetFramework="net452")

At the same time the code works fine if it is executed from UnitTest project (xUnit.Net) and the code itself is located in PCL library with .Net 4.5.0 target platform (nuget config line: package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.6" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10").

Could anybody advise the way how to customize which properties of custom exception type will be included into a Json string?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

```
ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver { IgnoreSerializableInterface = true, IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true };
```